# Median of 2 sorted Arrays

Tags: arrays, median

I am solving the question : https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/
on the LeetCode platform but the test cases are failing for the same .

Given below is the approach on the question :

```
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    double answer =0.0000d;
    int [] ans = new int [nums1.length+nums2.length];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    while(i<nums1.length && j<nums2.length){
         if(nums1[i]<nums2[j]){
             ans[k]=nums1[i];
             i++;
         }
         else{
             ans[k]=nums2[j];
             j++;
         }
         k++;
    }
    while(i<nums1.length){
        ans[k]=nums1[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<nums2.length){
        ans[k]=nums2[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    if((nums1.length+nums2.length)%2==0){
      answer= (ans[(ans.length)/2] +ans[((ans.length)/2)-1])/2;
    }
    else{
        answer = ans[(ans.length)/2];
    }
  return answer;
}
```

}

However for the Test case nums1={1,2} and nums2 ={3,4} the output should be 2.5 but my output is 2.0.

Comment: `(ans[(ans.length)/2] +ans[((ans.length)/2)-1])` returns an `int` because `ans` is an `int[]` thus, `(ans[(ans.length)/2] +ans[((ans.length)/2)-1])/2` is an integer division, which will remove all decimal places from the result. You have to cast one of your operands to `(double)` to receive a `double` as result .

Comment: But even if you manage to return the correct result here, your approach will probably fail in the tests because of the time limit. The challenge is requiring a `O(log(n+m))` but your approach is `O(n + m)`